# shared_from_this() of an instance that is not yet owned by shared_ptr always returns null?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I am trying to create a member function that returns whether it has stored to `shared_ptr`.

```
class X : public std::enable_shared_from_this {
    ...
    bool is_shared() const {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

...

(new X())->is_shared(); // -> false?
```

Is this legal? In this case, is shared_from_this() guaranteed to return null and not throw any exception?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this : *"It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17)std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the shared_ptr constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since C++17)."* It depends on which version of c++ you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible for `shared_from_this` to ever return `nullptr` in a well defined program.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks. I have read a manual based on C++11, but it did not say anything about this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`shared_from_this` can be used to obtain a `shared_ptr` from an object that is already managed by a `shared_ptr`.

Calling `shared_from_this` on a non-shared object is undefined behavior in C++11.

However, in C++17 `shared_from_this` will throw `bad_weak_ptr` and you can catch this exception:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class X : public std::enable_shared_from_this<X> {
  public:
    bool is_shared() const {
        try {
            shared_from_this();
            return true;
        } catch (std::bad_weak_ptr&) {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    X x;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << x.is_shared() << std::endl;
    auto y = std::make_shared<X>();
    std::cout << y->is_shared() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Furthermore you can use `weak_from_this` to get access to `weak_ptr`'s `expired` method:

```
bool is_shared() const {
    return !weak_from_this().expired();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @robinleander. Could you tell me where in the C++ 11 standard the "Calling shared_from_this ... is undefined behavior" is written?

Comment: Others have linked to it; see the notes section here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this

Comment: "the behavior is undefined" and "is undefined behavior" are same? I would like to know how it is written in ISO C++ standard sentences.

Comment: I believe the two are synonymous. In the article about UB they mention the phrase "The behavior is undefined if such program is executed". It would be very unwise to use this phrase without clarification if there were a difference.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub